# I am trying to execute a POST request but it is not getting executed?

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 to create a post request to store data as json. I set up everything following [this demo](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845) but the post request never returns a success or even a failure. I added toasts to see if it fails or succeeds but I never see them. Any help will be welcome.

this is my RetrofitClient class:

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
  }
}
```

this is my Api service Interface:

```
import com.community.jboss.visitingcard.Data.model.VisitingCard;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {

@POST("/posts")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<VisitingCard> saveVisitingCard(@Field("name") String name,
                                    @Field("email") String email,
                                    @Field("number") String number,
                                    @Field("id") int id,
                                    @Field("adress") String adress);
}
```

this is my ApiUtils class:

```
public class ApiUtils {

private ApiUtils() {}

public static final String BASE_URL = 
"http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

public static APIService getAPIService() {

    return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
  }
}
```

this is my model:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class VisitingCard {
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("number")
@Expose
private String number;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("adress")
@Expose
private String adress;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(String number){
    this.number = number;
}

public String getAdress(){
    return adress;
}
public void setAdress(String adress) {
    this.adress = adress;
 }
}
```

this is the code I use to run the post request in the Main activity:

in the OnCreate method:

```
mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();
```

When I click the button save this code gets executed:

```
 private void sendVisitCard(SharedPreferences settings) {
    mAPIService.saveVisitingCard(
    settings.getString("card_name",""),
    settings.getString("card_email",""), 
    settings.getString("card_phone",""),
    1,
    settings.getString("card_address", "") ).enqueue(new Callback<VisitingCard>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<VisitingCard> call, 
Response<VisitingCard> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(VisitingCardActivity.this,"Successfully 
stored your visiting card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<VisitingCard> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(VisitingCardActivity.this,"error while storing 
your visiting card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

this is the value of response.errorBody().string() Error:

```
Error: Insert failed, duplicate id
at Function.insert (/app/node_modules/lodash-id/src/index.js:49:18)
at /app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4388:28
at arrayReduce (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:683:21)
at baseWrapperValue (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4387:14)
at LodashWrapper.wrapperValue (/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:9050:14)
at create (/app/node_modules/json-server/lib/server/router/plural.js:221:52)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
(/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
```

this is the valuev of response.code: 500

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response is not successful. You have only checked the success scenario.

Consider adding else block in the method `onResponse`:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()) {
    Toast.makeText(VisitingCardActivity.this,"Successfully stored your visiting card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    // do something.
    // also check the value of `response.code()` and `response.errorBody().string()`
}
```

Comment: I thought onFailure plays the same role as that else

Comment: Well, you are wrong. `onFailure` gets called due to client side problem before calling the server, eg. network error, whereas `response.isSuccessful()` returns false because of the problem reported by server.

Comment: I have added the else method, and effectively there is an error but do you know how to know the error message

Comment: what is the value of `response.code()` and `response.errorBody().string()`?

Comment: I added everything

Comment: It clearly says duplicate id. Try different id other than `1` or refer the API documentation properly. But since the response code is 500, most probably it is not your fault. Some error handling is missing in the server side.

Comment: And when it  s not 1 THE POST  request fails

Comment: I just tried to run your API call using Postman, it showed the same error when the id is 1, whereas the response was `201 Created` when the id is `123`.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful if you post Json response.

if your json response starts with "[", then you need to add

```
Call<List<VisitingCard>> saveVisitingCard(@Field("name") String name,
                                @Field("email") String email,
                                @Field("number") String number,
                                @Field("id") int id,
                                @Field("adress") String adress);
```

incase "{"

```
Call<VisitingCard> saveVisitingCard(@Field("name") String name,
                                @Field("email") String email,
                                @Field("number") String number,
                                @Field("id") int id,
                                @Field("adress") String adress);
```

hope this will helps you. or try with putting else if not success means.

Comment: I checked your Json, This is the error you are facing with.

Comment: yes, you need add List<VisitingCard> in MainActivity onResponse